# Proving 2047 is not an euler pseudoprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol, pseudoprimes

Here is a textbook question that I don't know how to do:

n is an euler pseudoprime to the base b if gcd(b,n)=1 and if n satisfies

$b^{(n-1)/2} = (b/n)$ mod n (legendre symbol)

Questions:
Show that $2047 = 2^{11} − 1$ is not an Euler pseudoprime to the base 3 and conclude
from this that 2047 is a composite number

This is my problem; I must evaluate the quantity (b/n), however the legendre symbol is only defined for primes (am I right?) therefore, since 2047 is not a prime, how can I solve the question?

Comment: You need to show that $$3^{1023}\not\equiv \left(\frac 3n\right)\pmod{2047}$$

Comment: It's a Jacobi symbol.

Comment: In any event, if $3^{1024}\not\equiv \pm 3\pmod {2047}$, you are done.

Comment: ($3^{1024}\bmod{2047}$ is easier to compute than $3^{1023}$, via repeated squaring.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since gcd$(3,2047)=1$ and by definition we have to show that $$3^{(2047-1)/2} \equiv \bigg(\frac{3}{2047}\bigg)\pmod{2047} $$ And $$2047 = 23\cdot89$$ Then $$\bigg(\frac{3}{23}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{3}{89}\bigg) = -\bigg(\frac{23}{3}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{89}{3}\bigg)\qquad \text{by law of Quadratic Reciprocity} \\ = -\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg) \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \\ $$ By Legendre symbol we have $$\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)=-1$$ Hence $$\bigg(\frac{3}{23}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{3}{89}\bigg) = -1$$ Now we have to check whether $$3^{1023} \equiv -1 \pmod{2047} $$ OR $$3^{1024} \equiv -3 \pmod{2047} $$ But $$3^{1024} \not\equiv -3 \pmod{2047} $$ Thus, 2047 is not an Euler pseudoprime to base 3.

Comment: If you use $2047=23\cdot 89$ immediately, then it seems silly to go further and check if $2047$ is prime. Maybe it is better to compute $3^{1023} \pmod{2047}$ and see if it has a value that is neither $+1$ nor $-1$ modulo $2047$. In that case we have shown that $1023$ Is composite without searching for factors.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it is silly to do further computation once it is determined that $2047=23\cdot 89$ but the idea was to explain things in detail to the person who asked question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Shouldn't it be : "$\cdots$ we have shown that $2047$ is composite without searching for factors." ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, you are right; that must be what I meant back then.